# Python/PyGame Creating Random Monsters with Random Attributes from Class/Method

Tags: python, pygame

I am attempting to create a text based RPG. I want to use a Class Monsters to create a random monster of a particular type. However I cannot seem to access the random variables associated with the method in the class. Here is a trimmed down version of the code:

```
import random

class Monsters():

    def wolfEnemy(self):
        self.hp = random.randint(10, 20)
        self.attk = random.randint(1, 3)
        self.gold = random.randint(2, 5)
        self.xp = 100

monsters = Monsters()

print(monsters.wolfEnemy)

things = monsters.wolfEnemy.hp()

print(things)
```

I'm not sure how to access variables from within a instantiated method. `print(monsters.wolfEnemy)` just produces `None` and `things = monsters.wolfEnemy.hp()` errors with `builtins.AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'hp'`. Is there a way to call up that `wolfEnemy` and the attributes outside the Class/Method.

Comment: simply use `monsters.hp`

Comment: `wolfEnemy` in this case is not a separate object: the method is  modifying the instance of `Monsters` (here called `monsters`) directly. You should probably have a subclass for each type of monster (e.g. `class WolfEnemy(Monster): ...`), where `Monster` represents a single monster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `WolfEnemy` class that inherits from the `Monster` class. In the `Monster` class you can define attributes and methods that every subclass should have, and override them to create the specific subclasses.

```
import random


class Monster:

    def __init__(self):
        self.hp = random.randint(10, 20)
        self.attk = random.randint(1, 3)
        self.gold = random.randint(2, 5)
        self.xp = 100


class WolfEnemy(Monster):

    def __init__(self):
        # Call the __init__ method of the parent class, that means the
        # wolf instance will get the attributes that we've defined there.
        super().__init__()
        # To override specific attributes, assign new values here.
        self.hp = random.randint(20, 30)


wolf = WolfEnemy()
print(wolf.hp)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the result you want like this:

```
import random

class Monsters():
    def wolfEnemy(self):
        self.hp = random.randint(10, 20)
        self.attk = random.randint(1, 3)
        self.gold = random.randint(2, 5)
        self.xp = 100


monsters = Monsters()
# wolfEnemy() for the function call not wolfEnemy
monsters.wolfEnemy()
# monsters.hp get the attr not monsters.wolfEnemy.hp()
print(monsters.hp)
```